# Alarm Manager doesn't work after phone restart

Tags: java, android

When I set the alarm, and then restart my device, the alarm stops working. I registered `BroadcastReciver` correctly and created `Boot BroadCastReciver`, but it still doesn't work after device restart.

My code:

MainActivty for setting alarm for the first time:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("language","1");
        editor.commit();

        setRecurringAlarm(this);

    }

    private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tasks.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
    }
}
```

BroadcastReciver task:

```
public class Tasks extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName(context, Main2Activity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

Boot BroadcastReciver:

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, Tasks.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    .
    .
    .

    <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".Tasks"
        android:enabled="true">
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need service and broadcast receiver that wakeup your app when mobile is reboot. Here i have service code which may be help you (It perfectly works in my app).

**Service**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;


public class MyService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new GPSTracker(ReunirseService.this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

**Receiver** that will receive intent of Boot Completed and will start your service.

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        RestartServiceReceiver alarm = new RestartServiceReceiver();
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
            {
             Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService .class);
             context.startService(i);
            }

        }
    }
```

And you need to add permission of **RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and also you need to add filter

```
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: you don't add you service in your Manifest ? @AmrishKakadiya

Comment: Sorry, I've just forget to write here.. add `<service android:name=".MyService">`